# An item with the same key has already been added in Entity Framework Core SQL raw

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities,

`Book.cs`

```
public class Book 
{
   public int Id { get; set }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ReferenceNo { get; set; } 

   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

`Author.cs`

```
public class Author 
{
   public int Id { get; set }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   
   public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

For select all the books I am trying :

```
var query = "select * from Books as book join Authors as author on author.Id = book.AuthorId";

_context.Books.FromSqlRaw(query).ToList()
```

But I got the exception shown here, which tells me that `Name` column already exists, but I got confused because they are different types.

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Name```

Comment: Thanks for posting this question; I had the same error and I solved it as a result of this Q/A ... even though my entity object didn't have duplicated fields, my Procedure I was calling with `FromSqlRaw` inavertently returned 2 copies of one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Books and Authors both have a column called name. You should indicate in the query the table and field instead of select *

```
var query = "select book.Id, book.Name, book.ReferenceNo, author.Id, author.Name from Books as book join Authors as author on author.Id = book.AuthorId";

_context.Books.FromSqlRaw(query).ToList()
```

Also this class should be like this since AuthorId is already in the Author Class

```
public class Book 
{
   public int Id { get; set }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ReferenceNo { get; set; } 

   public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And if you need both `Name` columns, you **must provide** a column **alias** for at least one of them!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for your second answer, if you are not Including the Author then how should you get the AuthorId from a Book entity? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF Core why fall back to using raw SQL?
but i think u can use
inside your controller

```
public YourContext Context { get; }

public YourController(YourContext context)
    {
        Context = context;

    }

var book=Context .Books.Include(b => b.Author);
```

Comment: They're not asking for an alternative.